# How do I set Mailgun's recipient variables

Tags: arrays, mailgun

I'm trying to use Mailgun's [recipient variables](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#batch-sending). How do I create an array variable that looks like this:

```
{
  "user1@example.com" : {"unique_id": "ABC123456789", "unique_id_2": "ABC14"},
  "user2@example.com" : {"unique_id": "ZXY987654321", "unique_id_2": "ABC12"}
}
```

I know how to create ordinary arrays but this one is a bit different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer using PHP:

```
<?php

$array = array();
$array['user1@example.com'] = array('unique_id' => 'ABC123456789', 'unique_id_2' => 'ABC14');
$array['user2@example.com'] = array('unique_id' => 'ZXY987654321', 'unique_id_2' => 'ABC12');

echo json_encode($array);
```

This gives:

```
{
"user1@example.com":{"unique_id":"ABC123456789","unique_id_2":"ABC14"},
"user2@example.com":{"unique_id":"ZXY987654321","unique_id_2":"ABC12"}
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: If you're still happy then give me a green tick ;-)

Comment: I usually come back later because of the timer :)

Comment: @Chris...I need to do the same thing but in JavaScript. I know nothing about php, could you show a JavaScript solution? would be very appreciative. There appears to be some similarity but the assignment operators are breaking my attempts.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but can you include an array inside the recipient variables?